Blended in background color's opacity does not change with bg-opacity
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>humhum</title>
    </head>
    <body
        class="min-h-screen bg-base-200 bg-[url('/bg.webp')] bg-cover bg-center bg-fixed"
    >
        <div
            class="mx-auto px-4 bg-blend-normal backdrop-blur-sm text-white text-opacity-80 shadow-inner border border-white border-opacity-10 bg-scanlines max-w-2xl text-center min-h-screen bg-opacity-60"
        >
            <div>oh hey.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

See the bg-blend-normal. I want the main div to blend within background image I give bg-[url('/bg.webp')] in the parent body class. Problem is, whatever I change X value in bg-opacity-X opacity of the div's background color does not change. Let me know if this is "unreproducible I actually can change opacity" so I can give a better MRE.
edit: by blend in, I mean that main div will inherit the colour of background image I provide in body classes. then I can change the opacity of that colour

Are you trying to reduce the opacity of a certain part of the background image?

No, I am trying to reduce the opacity of the main div, which gets its colour from the background image defined in the body classes

But when opaque and semi-transparent colors (with the same hue) are overlaid, the result is still an opaque color. So even if you change the foreground color to semi-transparent, the final display will still be opaque. Additionally, your div is supposed to be transparent; it only has color because you added backdrop-blur. What you are actually modifying is not the background image color, but the color after backdrop-blur is applied to the div.

If you want to visually change the color of the body background image as it appears on the div, I suggest using appropriate backdrop-filters.

One more thing: even with the current approach, if you want to change the opacity of the div, you should change the opacity, not the bg-opacity. As mentioned earlier, the div doesn't have a background-color. bg-opacity is just a little trick in Tailwind for the CSS background-color property.
